# Unable to start apache2 after reinstall

Tags: apache2.4

I had an issue with my original install of apache2.4 on ubuntu14.
I have removed and purged the files in /etc/apache2 and reinstalled apache.
Now I am unable to start the server.
Can you please let me know if you have seen this issue before?

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 
Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/access_compat.load: 
Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_access_compat.so into server: 
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_access_compat.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a configuration file that's trying to load a library (`mod_access_compat.so`) that it can't find.

The file appears to be [part of the `apache2-bin` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=mod_access_compat.so&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any) so first check that that's installed (and that all its files are present) with:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install apache2-bin
```